# Find an element in an array, but the element can jump

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There is an array where all but one of the cells are 0, and we want to find the index of that single non-zero cell.  The problem is, every time that you check for a cell in this array, that non-zero element will do one of the following:

1. move forward by 1
2. move backward by 1
3. stay where it is.

For example, if that element is currently at position 10, and I check what is in `arr[5]`, then the element may be at position 9, 10 or 11 after I checked `arr[5]`.

We only need to find the position where the element is currently at, not where it started at (which is impossible).

The hard part is, if we write a for loop, there really is no way to know if the element is currently in front of you, or behind you.

Some more context if it helps:

1. The interviewer did give a hint which is maybe I should move my pointer back after checking x-number of cells.  The problem is, when should I move back, and by how many slots?
2. While "thinking out loud", I started saying a bunch of common approaches hoping that something would hit.  When I said recursion, the interviewer did say "recursion is a good start".  I don't know recursion really is the right approach, because I don't see how I can do recursion and #1 at the same time.
3. The interviewer said this problem can't be solved in O(n^2).  So we are looking at at least O(n^3), or maybe even exponential.

Comment: How big is the array meant to be ?

Comment: All I see that is possible is to implement some probability tool. Something like another array that stores the probability for each field that the element is at this position at the current time, assuming that every field had the same probability to be the first field of the element. And then access fields that significantly lower some probabilities. For this I would try out some stuff and see how the probability behaves to create the "perfect" algorithm out of experience. This is a stupid question for an interview. Might be just to see how you would approach this, without expecting a solution

Comment: This is extremely hard and very unclear as to how to even approach. I don't see a way to be 100% certain of a solution regardless of complexity...

Comment: Is it correct that when an index i is checked, if the non-zero element is at index (i+1), we read 0 as *jumps* occur after we obtained the value?

Comment: I have probably not got this, but since the probability of the non zero element **not** being on cell `i` approach zero as the number of reads grows, can you simply repeatedly read any cell until it becomes non zero? And since you are not given any constraint about what "*currently*" means, can you just return any index?

Comment: @MargaretBloom this has a worst case complexity of *`O(infinity)`*...

Comment: @Idos, Not really. Probability is an hard thing to grasp for programmers. While is true that there is indeed a non zero prob of looping infinitely, that probability is so small that is negligible, is it smaller than for example "Random universe breakdown due to unknown physic laws". And that doesn't bother you, do it? :)

Comment: Not all interview questions have good answers, or make sense. Sometimes a question is only asked in order to to see how you approach an impossible task. Other times they are just bad questions, period.

Comment: @MargaretBloom You are making assumptions here (e.g. that the probability of the element jumping is positive no matter which cell you are checking).

Comment: Does the 0 jumps before you get the answer to your query or afterwards?

Comment: @auburg, the array can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @ilim, yes, if I check (i), and the element is at (i+1), it could be at (i) after I checked (i).  The thing is, you don't know that.

Comment: @n.m, If I'm not wrong: Given a cell i, (wlog, we can assume i = 0) and the element on position k, compute the prob of the element not going in i after n reads.  The terms are all power of 1/3, which tends to 0 as n grows.

Comment: @Margaret Where do you get the 1/3 figure? See my comments in Patrick's answer.

Comment: @n.m. I assumed the probability is uniform. Unless stated otherwise this is usually an implicit assumption on probability problems.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I had no idea what are the usual assumptions of probability problems. However, where did you find a probability problem? The problem statement never mentions any probabilities, so please don't make any implicit assumptions thatvare customary for probability problems.

Comment: @n.m. it is impossible to guarantee the element will be found. If the RNG knows your moves, it can dodge your attempts reliably. The best you can do is to minimize the expected time to find the element. Now if you knew it always moved, the problem would be easy - just sweep twice, each time with a different PT parity. And if you knew it didn't move, just sweep once. Determining the worst case probability of not-moving (one that maximizes your expected time) might be an interesting challenge, but 1/3 is a reasonable guess because 1/3 gives you the least correlation between successive moves.

Comment: Also, it's safe to assume that p(left) = p(right), else the target would have the tendency to drift to one side and your best bet (not necessarily fastest, but reliable) would be to camp that side.

Comment: @JanDvorak "it is impossible to guarantee the element will be found" That's exactly right. Since we don't know what the interviewer really wanted beyond this simple answer, everything else is pure speculation. Everybody seems to be so sure that they expected a probabilistic solution, but why?

Comment: @n.m. either a probabilistic solution (and expected time is the only good metric I can think of), or a simplistic "impossible" solution (which might very plausibly be sufficient for the interviewer but is boring for us). I hope you're not suggesting we close as "unclear if you want a detailed answer"?

Comment: I'm going to run some tests to see which algorithm is better. Should be fun.

Comment: This can be solved using a [non deterministic turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine) :)

Comment: @Kent out of interest, what type of company was this an interview for ? Sure beats being asked the usual 'what is public, private and protected' question...

Comment: @auburg  this is a fairly large hardware company.

Answer (score 6):

**Tl;dr:** Your best bet is to keep checking each even index in the array in turn, wrapping around as many times as necessary until you find your target. On average you will stumble upon your target in the middle of your second pass.

---

First off, as many have already said, it is indeed impossible to ensure you will find your target element in any given amount of time. If the element knows where your next sample will be, it can always place itself somewhere else just in time. The best you can do is to sample the array in a way that minimizes the expected number of accesses - and because after each sample you learn nothing except if you were successful or not and a success means you stop sampling, an optimal strategy can be described simply as a sequence of indexes that should be checked, dependent only on the size of the array you're looking through. We can test each strategy in turn via automated means to see how well they perform. The results will depend on the specifics of the problem, so let's make some **assumptions**:

- The question doesn't specify the starting position our target. Let us assume that the starting position is chosen uniformly from across the entire array.
- The question doesn't specify the probability our target moves. For simplicity let's say it's independent on parameters such as the current position in the array, time passed and the history of samples. Using the probability 1/3 for each option gives us the least information, so let's use that.
- Let us test our algorithms on an array of <s>100</s> 101 elements. Also, let us test each algorithm one million times, just to be reasonably sure about its average case behavior.

The **algorithms** I've tested are:

- Random sampling: after each attempt we forget where we were looking and choose an entirely new index at random. Each sample has an independent 1/n chance of succeeding, so we expect to take n samples on average. This is our control.
- Sweep: try each position in sequence until our target is found. If our target wasn't moving, this would take n/2 samples on average. Our target is moving, however, so we may miss it on our first sweep.
- Slow sweep: the same, except we test each position several times before moving on. [Proposed by Patrick Trentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150068/499214) with a slowdown factor of 30x, tested with a slowdown factor of 2x.
- Fast sweep: the opposite of slow sweep. After the first sample we skip (k-1) cells before testing the next one. The first pass starts at ary[0], the next at ary[1] and so on. Tested with each speed up factor (k) from 2 to 5.
- Left-right sweep: First we check each index in turn from left to right, then each index from right to left. This algorithm would be guaranteed to find our target if it was always moving (which it isn't).
- Smart greedy: [Proposed by Aziuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36153379/499214). The idea behind this algorithm is that we track each cell probability of holding our target, then always sampling the cell with the highest probability. On one hand, this algorithm is relatively complex, on the other hand it sounds like it *should* give us the optimal results.

**Results:**

The results are shown as [average] ± [standard derivation].

- Random sampling: 100.889145 ± 100.318212

  At this point I have realised a fencepost error in my code. Good thing we have a control sample. This also establishes that we have in the ballpark of two or three digits of useful precision (sqrt #samples), which is in line with other tests of this type.
- Sweep: 100.327030 ± 91.210692

  The chance of our target squeezing through the net well counteracts the effect of the target taking n/2 time on average to reach the net. The algorithm doesn't really fare any better than a random sample on average, but it's more consistent in its performance and it isn't hard to implement either.
- slow sweep (x0.5): 128.272588 ± 99.003681

  While the slow movement of our net means our target will *probably* get caught in the net during the first sweep and won't need a second sweep, it also means the first sweep takes twice as long. All in all, relying on the target moving onto us seems a little inefficient.
- fast sweep x2: 75.981733 ± 72.620600
- fast sweep x3: 84.576265 ± 83.117648
- fast sweep x4: 88.811068 ± 87.676049
- fast sweep x5: 91.264716 ± 90.337139

  That's... a little surprising at first. While skipping every other step means we complete each lap in twice as many turns, each lap also has a reduced chance of actually encountering the target. A nicer view is to compare Sweep and FastSweep in broom-space: rotate each sample so that the index being sampled is always at 0 and the target drifts towards the left a bit faster. In Sweep, the target moves at 0, 1 or 2 speed each step. A quick parallel with the Fibonacci base tells us that the target should hit the broom/net around 62% of the time. If it misses, it takes another 100 turns to come back. In FastSweep, the target moves at 1, 2 or 3 speed each step meaning it misses more often, but it also takes half as much time to retry. Since the retry time drops more than the hit rate, it is advantageous to use FastSweep over Sweep.
- Left-right sweep: 100.572156 ± 91.503060

  Mostly acts like an ordinary sweep, and its score and standard derivation reflect that. Not too surprising a result.
- Aziuth's smart greedy: 87.982552 ± 85.649941

  At this point I have to admit a fault in my code: this algorithm is heavily dependent on its initial behavior (which is unspecified by Aziuth and was chosen to be randomised in my tests). But performance concerns meant that this algorithm will always choose the same randomized order each time. The results are then characteristic of that randomisation rather than of the algorithm as a whole.

  Always picking the most likely spot should find our target as fast as possible, right? Unfortunately, this complex algorithm barely competes with Sweep 3x. Why? I realise this is just speculation, but let us peek at the sequence Smart Greedy actually generates: During the first pass, each cell has equal probability of containing the target, so the algorithm has to choose. If it chooses randomly, it could pick up in the ballpark of 20% of cells before the dips in probability reach all of them. Afterwards the landscape is mostly smooth where the array hasn't been sampled recently, so the algorithm eventually stops sweeping and starts jumping around randomly. The real problem is that the algorithm is too greedy and doesn't really care about herding the target so it could pick at the target more easily.

  Nevertheless, this complex algorithm does fare better than both simple Sweep and a random sampler. it still can't, however, compete with the simplicity and surprising efficiency of FastSweep. Repeated tests have shown that the initial randomisation could swing the efficiency anywhere between 80% run time (20% speedup) and 90% run time (10% speedup).

Finally, here's the **code** that was used to generate the results:

```
class WalkSim
  attr_reader :limit, :current, :time, :p_stay
  def initialize limit, p_stay
    @p_stay = p_stay
    @limit = limit
    @current = rand (limit + 1)
    @time = 0
  end

  def poke n
    r = n == @current
    @current += (rand(2) == 1 ? 1 : -1) if rand > @p_stay
    @current = [0, @current, @limit].sort[1]
    @time += 1
    r
  end

  def WalkSim.bench limit, p_stay, runs
    histogram = Hash.new{0}
    runs.times do
      sim = WalkSim.new limit, p_stay
      gen = yield
      nil until sim.poke gen.next
      histogram[sim.time] += 1
    end
    histogram.to_a.sort
  end
end

class Array; def sum; reduce 0, :+; end; end

def stats histogram
  count = histogram.map{|k,v|v}.sum.to_f
  avg = histogram.map{|k,v|k*v}.sum / count
  variance = histogram.map{|k,v|(k-avg)**2*v}.sum / (count - 1)
  {avg: avg, stddev: variance ** 0.5}
end

RUNS = 1_000_000
PSTAY = 1.0/3
LIMIT = 100

puts "random sampling"
p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) { 
  Enumerator.new {|y|loop{y.yield rand (LIMIT + 1)}}
}

puts "sweep"
p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) { 
  Enumerator.new {|y|loop{0.upto(LIMIT){|i|y.yield i}}}
}

puts "x0.5 speed sweep"
p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) { 
  Enumerator.new {|y|loop{0.upto(LIMIT){|i|2.times{y.yield i}}}}
}
(2..5).each do |speed|
  puts "x#{speed} speed sweep"
  p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) { 
    Enumerator.new {|y|loop{speed.times{|off|off.step(LIMIT, speed){|i|y.yield i}}}}
  }
end
puts "sweep LR"
p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) { 
  Enumerator.new {|y|loop{
    0.upto(LIMIT){|i|y.yield i}
    LIMIT.downto(0){|i|y.yield i}
  }}
}

$sg_gen = Enumerator.new do |y|
  probs = Array.new(LIMIT + 1){1.0 / (LIMIT + 1)}
  loop do
    ix = probs.each_with_index.map{|v,i|[v,rand,i]}.max.last
    probs[ix] = 0
    probs = [probs[0] * (1 + PSTAY)/2 + probs[1] * (1 - PSTAY)/2,
             *probs.each_cons(3).map{|a, b, c| (a + c) / 2 * (1 - PSTAY) + b * PSTAY},
             probs[-1] * (1 + PSTAY)/2 + probs[-2] * (1 - PSTAY)/2]

    y.yield ix
  end
end

$sg_cache = []
def sg_enum; Enumerator.new{|y| $sg_cache.each{|n| y.yield n}; $sg_gen.each{|n| $sg_cache.push n; y.yield n}}; end

puts "smart greedy"
p stats WalkSim.bench(LIMIT, PSTAY, RUNS) {sg_enum}
```

Comment: Efficiency was never a concern of mine, however I appreciate this post a lot nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for doing the comparison. I think the interviewer was probably just looking for some variation of slow sweep, provided that I can explain it well.

Comment: I am wondering if you have the variance for each of those algorithms.  For example, slow sweep might be the slowest on average, but it may also have the smallest variance (e.g. will terminate within 150 iterations 90% of times).

Comment: @Kent Good point. Preliminary results say that the standard deviations are within 20% of each other and fast sweep is winning again. Let me crunch the big numbers, then I'll update the answer.

Comment: Truly surprising. Would you mind to combine my approach with the fast sweep approach in selecting between highest probabilities? If it is a weakness that it does no herding, let's try to do some, right? We could go that way: Find the highest probability, put every field that has a probability near that one in a choice and then choose in some fast sweep-alike manner (difference to last pick). Or, another approach to choose the pick: try to get the biggest possible distance to the last pick amongst sufficiently high probabilities. Maybe with a distance to the borders. That might herd.

Comment: I think there is a simplistic version of the probability algorithm that could work out quite well:
Sample randomly but with two conditions:
 -Never sample the first and last indices
-Never sample the same position or any of the two adjacents to your previous sampling.

The idea is that for those indices there are only two possible previous positions that lead there, while for the others there are three possible previous position (themselves and the neighbours).

Answer (score 0):

no forget everything about loops.
copy this array to another array and then check what cells are now non-zero. for example if your main array is mainArray[] you can use:

```
int temp[sizeOfMainArray]
int counter = 0;
while(counter < sizeOfArray)
{
    temp[counter] == mainArray[counter];
}
//then check what is non-zero in copied array
counter = 0;

while(counter < sizeOfArray)
{
    if(temp[counter] != 0)
{
    std::cout<<"I Found It!!!";
}
}//end of while
```

Comment: I doubt they meant to use such a "hack"

Comment: "copy this array to another array" Also make sure the element is not jumping while you are copying. Perhaps promise it a nice dinner in a fancy restaurant or something.

Comment: i think it's true because the question says when we check! in copy we don't check we just copy the array elements!

Comment: Accessing is checking. If you think accessing is not checking, why do you need an additional array? You could just as well say `temp = mainArray[counter]; if (temp) ...`. Which is just a silly cop out.

Comment: maybe you were right, but this is what i think can be.

Answer (score 0):

One approach perhaps :

i - Have four index variables f,f1,l,l1. f is pointing at 0,f1 at 1, l is pointing at n-1 (end of the array) and l1 at n-2 (second last element)

ii - Check the elements at f1 and l1 - are any of them non zero ? If so stop. If not, check elements at f and l (to see if the element has jumped back 1).

iii - If f and l are still zero, increment the indexes and repeat step ii. Stop when f1 > l1

Comment: *Check the elements at f1 and l1* - you are assuming that such simultaneous operation exists... Also remember that the element can jump twice during this

Comment: jeez - this is like the software equivalent to schrodinger's cat

Comment: Here's a case where this fails. Assume non-zero element X is at f,initially. You look for f1 and X stays still, and when you look for l1, ends up at index f1. Then you look for f and l, and X stays at f1 after those **two** checks. Once you update the indices, the invariant holds that X is on the leftmost index you keep and you can not detect it.

Answer (score 0):

**Iff** an equality check against an array index makes the non-zero element jump.

Why not think of a way where we don't really require an equality check with an array index?

```
int check = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    check |= arr[i];
    if(check != 0)
        break;
}
```

Orrr. Maybe you can keep reading `arr[mid]`. The non-zero element will end up there. Some day. Reasoning: Patrick Trentin seems to have put it in his answer (somewhat, its not really that, but you'll get an idea).

If you have some information about the array, maybe we can come up with a niftier approach.

Comment: The non-zero element is the one that jumps. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @ilim Sorry about that. Can you make the edit again? You should get the edit reputation credits.

Comment: @ilim Thanks for pointing out the error. What do you think about the approach?

Comment: No problem. I doubt if such a hack would be acceptable by the interviewer who asked it, although I also doubt if I care as she went with such a puzzling yet vague question.

Comment: @ilim Precisely. I think this is more of a question to see how you think than anything else, when faced with a 'not-quite-solvable' problem. I think repeated re-reading will probably be the way to go though, at least until I can come up with a better plan.

Comment: That's indeed a bold iff.

Comment: @n.m. I know :p   But the or portion is what I am leaning towards, as I keep thinking about it.

Comment: Or maybe the element can read your algorithm and decide to stay where it is.

Comment: @n.m. Picking an element a "random", and checking it. Indefinitely. Is the probability of that working, as compared to the probability of sticking to the same index, more or less?

Comment: What if the element knows your next move and chooses its own move accordingly?

Comment: @n.m. This array is fighting back. But, on a more serious note, your argument makes sense.

Comment: @n.m. Seems like Markov Chains or something that knows `state` can be useful here. But, we don't know much about the jumping of the non-zero value. Is it only probability based (back, stay, or front), or does it make the decision based on its previous decisions and/or the program's moves? Questions questions....

Comment: @n.m. Are you the interviewer in question? The one Kent was talking about?

Comment: Yes, such questions are usually formulatedbin terms of a game. You can check a cell and your opponent can move the non-zero element according to the rules. Your task is to come up with a winning strategy. If the opponent doesn't know your future moves, then checking cells at random eventually wins with probability 1. If he can read your mind, you lose no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the trivial case where the 1 is in the first cell of the array if you iterate through the array testing each element in turn you must eventually get to the position i where the 1 is in cell i+2. So when you read cell i+1 one of three things is going to happen.

1. The 1 stays where it is, you're going to find it next time you look
2. The 1 moves away from you, your back to the starting position with the 1 at i+2 next time
3. The 1 moves to cell you've just checked, it dodged your scan

Re-reading the i+1 cell will find the 1 in case 3 but just give it another chance to move in cases 1 and 2 so a strategy based on re-reading won't work.

My option would therefore to adopt a brute force approach, if I keep scanning the array then I'm going to hit case 1 at some point and find the elusive 1.

Comment: Think of this. The array know that you will be sticking to the same index. So, it decides to stick to its index.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. The array is no true array. This is obvious given the problem. We got some class that behaves somewhat like an array.
2. The array is mostly hidden. The only public operations are [] and size().
3. The array is obfuscated. We cannot get any information by retrieving it's address and then analyze the memory at that position. Even if we iterate through the whole memory of our system, we can't do tricks due to some advanced cryptographic means.
4. Every field of the array has the same probability to be the first field that hosts the one.
5. We know the probabilities of how the one changes it's position when triggered.

Probability controlled algorithm:

1. Introduce another array of same size, the probability array (over double).
   This array is initialized with all fields to be 1/size.
2. Every time we use [] on the base array, the probability array changes in this way:

   1. The accessed position is set to zero (did not contain the one)
   2. An entry becomes the sum of it's neighbors times the probability of that neighbor to jump to the entries position. (prob_array_next_it[i] = prob_array_last_it[i-1]*prob_jump_to_right + prob_array_last_it[i+1]*prob_jump_to_left + prob_array_last_it[i]*prob_dont_jump, different for i=0 and i=size-1 of course)
   3. The probability array is normalized (setting one entry to zero set the sum of the probabilities to below one)
3. The algorithm accesses the field with the highest probability (chooses amongst those that have)

It might be able to optimize this by controlling the flow of probabilities, but that needs to be based on the wandering event and might require some research.

No algorithm that tries to solve this problem is guaranteed to terminate after some time. For a complexity, we would analyze the average case.

Example:
Jump probabilities are 1/3, nothing happens if trying to jump out of bounds

Initialize:

- Hidden array: 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
- Probability array: 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8
  1/8 1/8 1/8

First iteration: try [0] -> failure

- Hidden array: 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 (no jump)
- Probability array step 1: 0
  1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8
- Probability array step 2: 1/24 2/24 1/8
  1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8 1/8
- Probability array step 2: same normalized (whole array * 8/7):
- 1/21 2/21 1/7
  1/7 1/7 1/7 1/7 1/7

Second iteration: try [2] as 1/7 is the maximum and this is the first field with 1/7 -> success (example should be clear by now, of course this might not work so fast on another example, had no interest of doing this for a lot of iterations since the probabilities would get cumbersome to compute by hand, would need to implement it. Note that if the one jumped to the left, we wouldn't have checked it so fast, even if it remained there for some time)

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, thank you for the hindsight :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin are you sure greedily grabbing the currently likeliest point is globally your best choice?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I'm not sure about my algorithm myself, see my edit in the lowest paragraph. If I had some more time, I would implement it and test it against an algorithm that does uniform random access.

Comment: @Aziuth the only perplexity I have with your odds is that I `assumed` the non-zero element would be able to jump across first/last locations in memory, whereas it seems that you didn't. @Jan Dvorak: his algorithm shows pretty well how in the long run scanning the same memory-location forever makes little sense, exactly what I pointed out in my answer. However, he also proposed a 'better' way to advance the search from one location to another, that is to follow the probability instead of my blind heuristic.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether he scans the same location once or a 30 times as I did, after a while that location's probability will be much lower than the remaining ones, making it necessary to move on and check another memory location. Choosing the memory location with the highest remaining probability is indeed the most sensible choice. Of course the reasoning holds under a uniform distribution assumption.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yes, his approach is clearly superior to checking every position multiple times. But is it the best approach possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't get your question right. Clearly, I'm waiting your answer for the best approach possible @JanDvorak ;)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin currently implementing SmartGreedy in my benchmark ;-)

Comment: Actually, depending on how you arbitrate equal probabilities at the start, SmartGreedy seems to perform up to about 1.5x worse than random sampling.

Comment: ... unless my target isn't moving properly (which it isn't, somehow)

Comment: Would you want to share a public repo for cross-validation?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I've fixed the issue and now I'm running my code with a lot of samples, then I'll post the code along with an answer. The results are a bit surprising and while SmartGreedy isn't the worst, it's been surpassed significantly by a surprising contender.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149346/find-an-element-in-an-array-but-the-element-can-jump/36161342#36161342). Feel free to review my code thoroughly and tell me any improvements that shoud be made.